# Python GTK Image, Change Image Constantly gets none image after a many times

Tags: python, image, gtk, pygtk

I have a Gtk.Image widget in a window, and it must change image after a time.
it run in a thread of function below

```
    def dinChangeBg(self,_Timing):
        tm.sleep(int(_Timing))

##      Verifica se a janela ainda existe
        if not(self.Runing):
            thread.exit()

        bg = "image/background"+str(self.bgIndex)+".jpg"

        if not (os.path.isfile(bg)):
            print(bg,"bg inesistente")
            self.bgIndex = 1

            bg = "image/background"+str(self.bgIndex)+".jpg"

        if(os.path.isfile(bg)):
            print("new bac", bg)

            pbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale(bg, self.Window.get_size()[0],self.Window.get_size()[1], preserve_aspect_ratio=False)
            self.image.clear()
            self.image.set_from_pixbuf(pbuf)
            self.bgIndex += 1


        self.dinChangeBg(int(_Timing))
```

the thread call is:

```
_thread.start_new_thread(dinChangeBg,(60,))
```

after a time it no change more the image and a image desappears,
the print continues to show a image location if it exists .

someone have a idea of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call GTK+ functions from another thread. Your thread will have to tell the GTK+ thread to **both** create the pixbuf **and** change the image; you do the telling with `GLib.idle_add()`. Or, if this is an animation that is simple enough that you can forego the second thread entirely, use `GLib.timeout_add()` to run the code on a timeout.

Comment: after try it, the Gtk.Window are not showing,  act like will open with shadow, bus show nothing,

i started GLib thread , and do GLib.idle_add(dinChangeBg,60),
is start thath tread perfetly but window dont show

Comment: i have a while loop and time.sleep on thread and it break a program. i changed the thread and now it works ok. thanks